# How to choose Android sdkVersion properly?

Tags: android, sdk

everyone!

I'm new to android programming, so simple things sometimes become a problem.

I have my application. It should work on devices with Android 5 and higher. 
The question is what is proper strategy of sdkVersion defining?

What I mean.

For example, I need to acheive permision to use bluetooth. 
If my target sdkVersion is 7 and minimum sdkVersion is 5 I should ask permission in manifest file and then acheive it in runtime. Like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
...
}
```

But if my target sdkVersion is 5 even `Build.VERSION_CODES.M` cannot be resolved.

So the question is : what is proper approach  to choose sdkVersion? Where can I read about it?

I read here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target

but I didn't get what is best practice. So please share your experience.

Comment: For android 5.0 sdkversion is 21 -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this article from Ian Lake: [Picking your compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, and targetSdkVersion](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd)

**compileSdkVersion:**

> compileSdkVersion is your way to tell Gradle what version of the
>   Android SDK to compile your app with. Using the new Android SDK is a
>   requirement to use any of the new APIs added in that level.

**minSdkVersion:**

> If compileSdkVersion sets the newest APIs available to you,
>   minSdkVersion is the lower bound for your app. The minSdkVersion is
>   one of the signals the Google Play Store uses to determine which of a
>   user’s devices an app can be installed on.

**targetSdkVersion:**

> The most interesting of the three, however, is targetSdkVersion.
>   targetSdkVersion is the main way Android provides forward
>   compatibility by not applying behavior changes unless the
>   targetSdkVersion is updated. This allows you to use new APIs (as you
>   did update your compileSdkVersion right?) prior to working through the
>   behavior changes.

Ideally, the relationship would look more like this in the steady state:

> minSdkVersion (lowest possible) <= 
>       targetSdkVersion == compileSdkVersion (latest SDK)

Comment: If `minSdkVersion` <= `compileSdkVersion` (of course), does it mean that I can never know will it work on device with `minSdkVersion` until I test it? There is no other way to check it. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is always a best practice to test in all the supported API levels of your app -- from `minSdkVersion` to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using Android Studio and build.gradle. If not, I recommend you to get it. All of the following is relevant for Android Studio and gradle build system.

Your main mistake is that **SDK version in `build.gradle` of `app` module is not the same as Android Version**. [Here](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers) is the list of Platform Codenames, Versions, API Levels. What you need for SDK version is number in API level column of first table.

This is how `android` section of `build.gradle` for app targeting Android 5.0 and newer should look like.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.eraga.myobjectives"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about `targetSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd).

In this case, your `minSdkVersion` should be 21 (android 5.0) and `targetSdkVersion` along with `compileSdkVersion`should be 25 (android 7.1).